# How does the Stellar Network tell the difference between a newly issued token and a Lumen?

Tags: xlm, lumens, token, assets, ico

When issuing a new token (as part of an ICO or otherwise), how is this new token differentiated from a Lumen (or any other token) within the Stellar Network?

For example, in the case of a new MOBI token being issued, how does the network know that this is a MOBI and not another token? Where in the token's signature is the type of token specified?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assets in Stellar network are represented as a pair that consists of:

- the code of the asset (ex. `MOBI`)
- the issuer account of the asset (ex. `GA6HCMBLTZS5VYYBCATRBRZ3BZJMAFUDKYYF6AH6MVCMGWMRDNSWJPIH`)

Everyone can issue `MOBI` token from another account but the issuer part of the asset will be different.

#### More info

- [Assets](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html)
- [Distributed exchange](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/exchange.html)
- [Issuing assets](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/issuing-assets.html)